# Craft search only shows results matching 'title' of entries

Tags: craft3, search

I´m doing a search on Blog entries, i want to get all relevant entries searching on several fields, and seems that only matches the title. I try already using search(query), now i added the fields, same result. Maybe the search item should be re-generated? i don´t know how to do it in console, but i have only 4 blog entries at the time, i already change and saved all of them, same result...

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

```
{% paginate craft.entries({
             search: 'title:' ~ query ~ ' OR categoriaBlog:' ~ query ~ ' OR etiquetasBlog:' ~ query ~ ' OR resumenBlog:' ~ query ~ ' OR subtituloBlog:' ~ query ~ ' OR contenidoBlog:' ~ query,
             orderBy: 'score',
             section: 'blogSec'
        })
        .limit(6) as pageInfo, blogs %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Search via `search()` can be used only for text fields, if you want to search by categories or records you need to use the `relatedTo()` method, also do not forget to specify search keywords when creating the field.

[image]

Links: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/relations.html#terminology, https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/searching.html#supported-syntaxes.

Practical example:

```
{% set searchResults = [] %}
  
{% set queryParamsText = queryParamsText|merge({
        search: {
            query: 'title:' ~ searchWord
        }
     }) 
%}

    {% set category = craft.categories.group('category').search(searchWord).one() %}

    {% set relatedParams = relatedParams|merge([{ targetElement:category }]) %}

    {% if relatedParams|length > 1 %}
        {% set queryParamsRelated = queryParamsRelated|merge({'relatedTo':relatedParams}) %}
    {% endif %}

{% set searchResultsText = craft.entries(queryParamsText).section('canAddSectionHandleOrId') %}

{% set searchResultsRelated = craft.entries(queryParamsRelated
).section('canAddSectionHandleOrId') %}

{% set searchResults = searchResultsText|merge(searchResultsRelated)|unique %}
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for your response.
Question: Can´t i search text con category title or tags title? Docs says that i can search on those attributes.
And matrix fields with Redactor rich text?

Comment: I will try your solution and check in deep the links, thank you!

Comment: @Sebastián. It's my pleasure. In a text search, you will search for your category titles and reach text, Craft CMS will give you the essence where this text appears.